# How to change the Windows 98 boot logo?

Tags: windows, boot, windows-98

so I learned that it's easy to change Android device boot logos and stuff.

Windows boots with WinLoad.exe, which calls a GPU to draw the logo.

Is it possible I can decompile Windows OS in pieces and alter source of WinLoad.exe and re-compile it to show whatever I want in boot logo?

Answer (score 3):

What you want to modify is [Logo.sys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LOGO.SYS).  It is fairly straight-forward to do so, read and understand that Wiki page for the details.

Comment: The last three paras are worth a quote. This was a favorite pastime of techies back in the day, and it's very easy to achieve. I'm sure there are plenty of guides online, and even various programs that do this automatically using supplied images. But if you understand the description in the wiki you can make your own screen in nothing more than MS Paint.